# using Block to transfer from class A to class B in iOS

Tags: ios, block

I have 2 class A and B. I want transfer data from A->B use block.

eg:

Class A: I have one label with textLabel is "This is class A" .

Class B: I have one label and one button "Submit". textLabel is "This is class B"

When tapping the "Submit "button in class B, I want to dismiss to class A and textLabel in class A to change to "This is class B" as text label in class B. 
Thanks!

Comment: Well you have my permission to do that.

Comment: This comment needs to be upvoted so much.

Comment: Not really; it's flippant and unhelpful.

Comment: Just like the question. Which is no question.

Comment: Of course; however the correct comment should be "please attempt a solution first and come back if you hit any errors with your implementation".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I keep guessing you have something like 2 view controllers where second is pushed or presented over the first one. When the user presses some button the second controller is to be dismissed or popped and the value on some label is to be changed according to some data the second view controller is holding.

If I am near the reality then the most common solution is using delegates. That means the second view controller would have a weak reference to the first one which can be used to call a specific method on the first controller which would update the data according to the second view controller.

I guess the blocks could be used to accomplish the same but this might be dangerous for memory leaks. Anyway, your class B could have an initialiser or a property that takes a block as the input argument. Class B should then save this block and call it at some specific time like when user presses something.

Something like this:

```
- (void)initWithCallback:(void(^)(NSString *newText))callback;// Class B

- (void)presentBClass {
    [[BClass alloc] initWithCallback:^(NSString *newText) {
        self.label.text = newText;
    }]
} //Class A
```

Comment: What do using block instead delegate make danger for memory?            Thank!

Comment: Well, just for the purpose of memory retaining we can act as if the block was a class C. Then in the case above C retains A (by calling "self" in block), A probably retains B (is its owner) and B retains C as it needs to hold the block. That means none of them will be released by itself until one of those connections is removed: If B contains block callbackBlock then after you call callbackBlock(myString) you should also call callbackBlock = nil to prevent this.